# HP PAVILION NOTEBOOK PC DV6880 Blue Screen

Tags: laptop, graphics-card

Environment : Win-Vista 64 BIT

Graphics Processor / Vendor NVIDIA GeForce 8400M GS
Video Memory 256 MB
Total Available Graphics Memory 1535 MB

What happens is, i can use the laptop in "basic theme" ONLY, the moment i enable any aero theme, the screen tears up, discoloration appears & then laptop freezes. Sometimes its reboot itself with Blue Screen shows up the gfx card error.

Any way around, highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check that your video card drivers are up to date.

Comment: Yes, i updated the driver/ tested with rollback.

Comment: Is it the issue with the Motherboard ? I can feel the heating issue as well.

Comment: It's possible that the problem is heat related.  But I would be suspicious of that since it only happens when you change to an aero theme.  Blowing the laptop out with a can of compressed air probably won't hurt.

Comment: Definitely sounds like it could be heat related. Aero requires accelerated graphics, which will use the GPU more heavily, and could result in overheating. The dv6 series is notorious for overheating. @Mike's suggestion is a good one - try getting any excess dust out.